Self-contradiction by Schrödinger equation
There are $2$ observers or frames, $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$. They have the same origin but different orientations of $x,y,z$ axes. Suppose the angle between the $z$ axes is $\theta_z \neq (\pi/2)$. Now, there is a proton or hydrogen nucleus at the origin of both frames. Both observers at $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ solve the Schrödinger equation and find that the $p_z, \, p_x, \, p_y$ orbitals of the hydrogen atom are along the $z, \, x, \, y$ axes of their respective frames. Now, if the Schrödinger equation for $\text{A}$ is correct, the $p_z$ orbital is along its $z$ axis, which is not the $z$ axis or any axis of $\text{B}$. A similar argument follows for $\text{B}$. That means the Schrödinger equation is incorrect for any other rotated frame if it is correct for one particular frame. Does the Schrödinger equation contradict itself, or is something wrong with my argument?

Why do you think the atom cares what axes you assign to it?

$z’$ is different from $z$, and the $p_{z’}$ orbital is different from the $p_z$ orbital.

@JonCuster Not the atom but the schrodinger equation seems to care about choice of axes . Because the entire probability density gets affected by changing axes as predicted by schrodinger equation .

In this case the Schrödinger equation is rotation invariant.

If the Schrodinger equation were self-contradictory, it wouldn’t take a century for physicists to notice this.

So that we can situate your understanding: Do you know that (or what it means that) the orbitals are eigenstates of the Hydrogen atom Hamiltonian? Do you know what the "term" degeneracy means in this context? Are you aware that the hydrogen orbitals are not the only states that a hydrogen atom can be in (that is, that a hydrogen atom can be in a superposition of orbitals)?  Answering these questions for us will help us clear up your confusion.  (Another question: are you coming from a chemistry background, and if so, have you know any physical chemistry?)

@march firstly I know that the orbitals are hamiltonian or energy eigenstates (that's what TISE solution is ) . Secondly I know that two or more eigenstates are called degenerate states if they have same eigenvalue (energy eigenvalue in this case ) . Example: $2s,2p_x,2p_y,2p_z$ are degenerate energy eigenstates for hydrogen atom . Thirdly I knew that eigenstates can be in superposition but missed thinking that way for the hydrogen orbitals (I think I got the answer). Fourthly I had chemistry in my high-school.

Orbitals that you get by solving time-independent Schr. eq. are not necessarily the actual psi function realized in any real system. This procedure just finds basis functions related to coordinate frame axes, and it is fine that these look the same in differently oriented frames (and thus when comparing orbitals $p_x$ from two such frames, they are obviously not the same object). Values of the basis functions in one frame are related to values of the basis functions in differently oriented frame via rotation transformation matrix, just as components of 3D vectors would be.

There is something wrong with your argument. What observer A calls $p_z$ will be described by observer B as some linear combination $p_z = ap_{x'} + bp_{y'} + cp_{z'}$. There is nothing inconsistent in this. That such a description will be possible for any relative orientation of the two observers is guaranteed by the fact that the p-orbitals taken together form a representation of the rotation group $SO(3)$ (indeed, so do all the different types of eigenstates of the Hydrogen atom).
